# Python decoding error on Excel with xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I know this is a recurrent subject but I'm facing a encoding/decoding error when trying to parse an Excel file (.xlsx) opened with `xlrd`

```
    value = sheet.cell(row,col).value
    value = value.decode('utf-8') // also tried cp1252 and iso-8859-15
```

`WARNING: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position xx: ordinal not in range(128)`

[xlrd doc](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unicode.html) says that From Excel 97 onwards, the text in Excel spreadsheets has been stored as Unicode. So decoding should not even be necessary.

Any idea what should be done ?

P.S. My Excel file has some *é* and *à* inside.

Comment: `\xe9` is indeed `é`. Have you tried `'latin-1'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still using Python 2? :(

If what you're trying to do is convert from `unicode` to UTF-8 encoded `str`, you need to `value.encode('utf-8')`, not `decode`.

Comment: Yeah I originally wrote my script in Python 3 so it was not an issue. encode does the job thanxs.